# Is Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty safe to use in older versions of iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=hasownproperty), `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` has "unknown support" for even relatively modern browsers, accounting for roughly 10% of browser share, including iOS versions as recent as this past year.

From what I can tell, some [older versions of Opera](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/f4368f69e164b828e82f1a8b194adef967dd5d0f/closure/goog/base.js#L1477) *did* have an issue with this, but "Opera 10-63" is a pretty broad range and I assume it's been fixed for more than just 2 months.

Are there any known issues or gotchas with this API on any browser with even remotely reasonable usage?

Comment: I think caniuse.com is wrong. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#Browser_compatibility) says it's compatible with most browsers going back many versions.  It was in the JavaScript 1.5 specification.

Comment: I think the concern isn't whether it's in ES3, but that there are broken implementations in some older browsers that supposedly implement that spec.

Comment: Opera 15 switched to Chromium.